# In jquery, how can I set the background-image of an element without hardcoding the url of the image in my javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image element that I can reference by its `class` and/or `id` and I have a `div`.  I want to set the `background-image` of the div to the image element, but I don't want to hardcode the url path in my JavaScript code.

How can I do this? I saw lots of answers to this but they all hardcoded the url in the JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do this:

```
$("#div-id").css("background-image", "url(" + $("#image-id").attr("src") + ")");
```